# Protesting/Disputing Appraisal Increase on Unimproved Land

Tags: united-states, texas, dispute, appraisal, land

I live in Texas and own about 13 acres of (farm) land.  The appraisal for the land went from ~$165K last year to ~$270K this year, an increase of about ~63%.  There is nothing distinctive, either pro or con, about this land, really.  About the only thing that *might* have changed, as far as the county's calculations may be concerned, is they understand I am in the process of building a home on it this year although that project may not actually be complete this year.

Typically people dispute the appraisal of a home (i.e. the combined appraised value of a house and the land it's on), with the primary basis of the dispute being for the improvement as opposed to just the land.  So I am wondering if a protest or dispute process will be of any likely benefit for my situation, given it is just land?

Does anyone have any direct, or even indirect, experience with this?

Comment: Did you need to get permission to build the home? Not sure how things work in the US, but in the UK (as I think I understand it), the value of "_land with permission to build_" is higher than just "_land_", even if the building work hasn't even begun.

Comment: @TripeHound: thanks for the thought.  We do have "zoning" laws and whatever.  Land in question has not had any changes to its status like this, though.  My goal is to understand if formally protesting/disputing the valuation -- something that is determined both somewhat statistically and somewhat arbitrarily -- is worth attempting.   It usually requires some offer of proof by the owner that the valuation is incorrect for some reason, and all I'd likely have is "there's no way land value increases this much in a year...you are just making this up".

Comment: There is a land bubble. Are you sure your land isn't now worth that much?

Comment: "Are you sure your land isn't now worth that much?" No, I am >>not<< sure :--)  But it's hard to be sure what the actual value is and it's not clear to me the county actually knows what the value is.  So I am trying to understand >>on what basis<< I could appeal/dispute their valuation.  I think the answer is probably "nothing", or "have to hire an independent appraiser".  So I thought I'd check here for thoughts, first.

Comment: If you are in the process of building a home, has the "farmland" been improved in any way such as having electrical supply line installed to which you can connect, or will you be "completely off the grid" with your own solar panels or other generators for electricity, septic tank for sewage, and a well for water supply, wireless for Internet service, etc?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: at the moment (i.e. at time valuation was determined back before new year) the is (and was) no electricity service or sewer or anything...just flat land.  I will need electric company to install poles, wires, meter, and city to hook up water.  But that should not have affected current valuation as far as I can tell.